# Is it possible in liferay to create a render URL without a request object?

Tags: java, liferay

I know how to create a render url when I have PortletRequest but if I don't?
Something similar to:

```
PortletURLFactoryUtil.create(portletRequest, portletId, plid, lifecycle)
```

but without a portletRequest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Liferay, `javax.portlet.PortletURL` is implemented by [`com.liferay.portlet.PortletURLImpl`](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portlet/PortletURLImpl.java). Each constructor of `PortletURLImpl` expects `PortletRequest` or `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter.

So, strictly speaking, with Liferay Java API, it's not possible to create portlet url without a request object.

If you don't want to pass request object as a parameter to your code, you can always somehow hide it away. For example, `portlet:renderURL` JSP tag has no request parameter, but it obtains the request object from the current `javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext`.

Similarly, your Java code could use sort of portlet / servlet filter that would store the request object in a `ThreadLocal` or other thread-bound storage and keep it there during request processing.

Anyway, portlet urls are so much bound to request processing that I see no reason to bother.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Yes you can.
In javaScript

```
function(event) {
    var portletURL = Liferay.PortletURL.createRenderURL();
    portletURL.setParameter('groupId', '<%= scopeGroupId %>');
    portletURL.setParameter('struts_action', '/journal/select_document_library');
    portletURL.setPlid('<%= controlPanelPlid %>');
    portletURL.setPortletId('15');
    portletURL.setWindowState('pop_up');
    Liferay.Util.openWindow(
        {
            id: '<portlet:namespace />selectDocumentLibrary',
            uri: portletURL.toString()
        }
    );
}
```

Goto [Creating Portlet URLs in JavaScript](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/creating-portlet-urls-in-javascript-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-07-en)

or in Jsp page as

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/portlet" prefix="liferay-portlet" %>
<liferay-portlet:renderURL var="openPortletURL" copyCurrentRenderParameters="true" portletMode="<%=LiferayPortletMode.VIEW.toString() %>" 
  windowState="<%=LiferayWindowState.NORMAL.toString()%>">
  <liferay-portlet:param name="param" value="This is from Liferay TAG"/>
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<a href="${openPortletURL}">Render Url created by Liferay TAG in JSP</a>
```

Goto [Creating Render Url using liferay-portal](http://www.opensource-techblog.com/2014/12/create-render-url-by-liferay-tag.html)

Comment: Good answer, but I think it is missing the point: The first option is only available in the browser and it seems that the OP is search for something on the server. And the second option is an implicit access to the `PortletRequest` - you can't use it without a request.